# Angular child route in sub outlet

Tags: javascript, angular

In my TestComponent I have a navbar with the links to multiple components that I want to display in a sub router outlet which is in the TestComponent, but it throws this error.

> core.js:6237 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match
>   any routes. URL Segment: 'dashboard/test/id'

```
const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard/test',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        children: [
          {
            path: 'test',
            component: TestComponent,
            children: [
              {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'id',
                pathMatch: 'full'
              },
              {
                path: 'id',
                component: IdComponent,
                outlet: 'sub'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

Comment: Can you share your routerLinks html code?

Comment: You does not have any router configiration with leo path?

Comment: ```<li routerLink="/dashboard/test/id">Run ID</li>```

Comment: routerLink configuration for named  router will be differet syntax. I think you have made some syntax error can you create stackblitz?

Comment: It doesn't matter right now. If I change the url in the browser it's not working as well.

Comment: Can you remove outlet property from router configration object and check?

Comment: If I remove that, it works, but then it doesn't load in the sub outlet.

Comment: The syntax for named routelet is different check this:https://angular.io/guide/router#add-a-secondary-route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routerLink should be

`[routerLink]="['/dashboard/test', {outlets: { sub: ['id'] } }]"`